# Zurb Foundation Mobile Menu Does Not Work with Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming, zurb-foundation

I tried a lot, but I can't figure out, why Wordpress does not let my Menu work.
In the static version everything works perfectly fine. But implemented in Wordpress, for some reason, the files are loaded but not executed. Without an error message.

I uploaded my local theme and the static version here:

[**wordpresstest**](http://wordpresstest.horyzon.de) <-- Not working dynamic Wordpress version

[**wordpresstest2**](http://wordpresstest2.horyzon.de) <-- Working static version

I read somewhere, that wordpress, loads jQuery in noConflict mode, and that I should modify my foundation.js in a way, that it is compatible with wordpress. But I have no idea, what exactly to do right now.

Answer (score 0):

add this js

```
jQuery(".has-dropdown").hover(function(){
   jquery(".top-bar-section .dropdown").css("display","block");
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I have to reopen the thread. The dropdown opens, but not the mobile version. If you make screen smaller, then the navigation menu collapses. It should open by pressing the button, but it doesn't. I am talking about the mobile version.

Comment: Did you fix this as I'm seeing the same problem, top bar drop downs work but the mobile doesn't appear when the toggle button is pressed.